# How to change navigation bar background and text color of 'more' tab in the most efficient way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, tabbar

I am using the following UINavigation delegate method in my app delegate to update the navigation bar background and text color for all my view controllers (so that I do not have to repeat code for every view controller in the stack.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This has been working fine for all my tabs in the app except for the "more" tab. I now have more than one view controller in the 'more tab'

Is it possible to invoke the UINavigation delegate method for the 'more' tab as well? Else what is the best alternative to change the navbar and text color of all the view controllers in the more tab without repeating code for all the view controllers.

Comment: Are you doing this by changing the tint color of the navigation bar and setting a custom titleview on the navigation item?  Also are you setting the same color in all of your view or a different one for each?

Comment: @Dave.B yes I am changing the tint color and custom titleview and I want the same color for all my pages

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to do the same thing many times.  My solution is to create a super class that inherits UIViewController and then customizes the nav bar in view did load. Then inherit this super class with all of your view controllers.

This solution puts all of your custom nav bar changes into one spot so if you want to change colors or add images you only have to do it in that one superclass.  This is a great use of inheritance and code reuse which will keep your classes free of duplicated code.

Comment: UITabBarController provides its own view controller for the navigation bar and table view in the “More” tab. I don’t think your solution—good idea though it be—will help here.